# Using Amazon's API to find a product's UPC (Python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-product-api

I've been trying to create a python script that uses a product's ASIN to return (via Amazon's API) its UPC. The module I've attempted to use thusfar is python-amazon-product-api (http://packages.python.org/python-amazon-product-api/), but it doesn't appear that this module supplies the UPC (or, at least, I can't find it under a product's attributes). Is this possible using this module? If not, what should I switch to? Here's what I have so far:

```
import amazonproduct
SECRET_KEY = 'xxx'
AWS_KEY = 'yyy'
api = amazonproduct.API(AWS_KEY,SECRET_KEY,'us')
node = api.item_lookup('B001OXUIIG')
```

And, again, the UPC doesn't appear to be under node.Items.Item.ItemAttributes . Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The item_lookup call only gets basic information. You will need to use the ResponseGroup parameter to specify what information you want Amazon to return (see [Amazon's ItemLookup  Documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2010-11-01/DG/ItemLookup.html) for more information). If you want to get additional product attributes, you should request the "Medium" response group. Your API call would look like:

```
node = api.item_lookup('B001OXUIIG', ResponseGroup='Medium')
```

Under itemAttributes, you should see the upc field (which is "092633186909" for the item you are looking for).

Comment: Try ``str(node.Items.Item.ItemAttributes.UPC)``